# Can I use Argo Tunnel to connect my clusters together without exposing to the internet?

Tags: linux, cloudflare, cloudflare-argo

Note that I'm newbie in Argo tunnel

I have several servers in different locations and only a set of them exposed to the internet. (Lets say there is two sets, backend and frontend.

I want to coonect from frontend to backend using Argo tunnel like they are on the same machine. Lets say, I have setup Nginx with `proxy_pass http://backendde:8008`! Now, `backendde` is a name for one of my backends. (or set an IP like `10.25.36.1`)

Maybe, my question can be: "How can I expose one server to another using Argo tunnel?"

Note that I cant edit `/etc/hosts` (its a PaaS/kubernate) so, I have to assign a fixed local IP for each instance.

I have this

```bash
/root/cloudflared tunnel --no-autoupdate run --token $TUNNEL_TOKEN --protocol http2 $TUNNEL_NAME
```

and I dont know how to set a fixed IP for my instances and then call this IP from another server (with argo setup)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

what you want to do is called "connecting private networks" on Argo tunnels lingo.
You will need to deploy a "WARP" client on one end, and a cloudflared daemon on the other end, to be able to route traffic on the cloudflare edge network (without exposing the host to the internet).

See details here:
https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/private-net/connect-private-networks/

Comment: Thanks  and the connection type will be WARP (wiregaurd)? Am I right?

Comment: correct, the connections will be WARP "clients".

Comment: thank you so much. Sorry, I dont have enough reputation to give an upvote 

Comment: it's ok. Don't worry :)